# Make parent div transparent, but only where the child is

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a background-image (in my example just red) and a row which should have a background-color (in my example blue) and a with of 100%.

The problem is that inside the blue bar there should be a transparent logo (fixed width 200px), but it should be transparent to let through the background-image of the body (in my example red).

**Example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="logo">
    Should be transparent to the red background
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uamgevLo/2/

Any suggestions how this might be done?

Comment: Note the Fiddle is different to your code example. The logo div is transparent in your code, you can see the `row` coming through behind - is is that not what you want? I'm unsure what the image is, does it act differently when you use an actual image?

Comment: Do you mean, it will go through the blue layer and show red there?

Comment: you want background of body when implement transparent logo, isn't it?

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/uamgevLo/5/

You can split the row part into 3 part. left bar, right bar, and logo box. for left and right bar, I'll use pseudo element (before and after), and position absolute it

```
.logo {
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.logo::before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(50vw - 100px);
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.logo::after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(50vw - 100px);
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using flex and splitting the top row in three.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
}

#Lft,#Rgt{
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.logo {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 200px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="Lft"></div>
  <div class="logo">
    Should be transparent to the red background
  </div>
  <div id="Rgt"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using [`linear-gradient`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients), so you don't have to split your `.row` into columns:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    blue, 
    blue calc(50% - 100px), 
    transparent calc(50% - 100px), 
    transparent calc(50% + 100px), 
    blue calc(50% + 100px), 
    blue
  );
}
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="logo">Should be transparent to the red background</div>
</div>
```